# C# stack trace contains random letters

Tags: c#, .net-core, .net-5

When looking at stack traces from release build .net 5 code I see stack traces that look like this:

```
Server: Session 58084: Error: System.NotSupportedException: Specified method is not supported.
at My.Application.Code.ThrowsError() in C:\a\3\s\My\Application\Code.cs:line 292
at uzctz.xcdpf.uzctz.vafjj`1.phljb(shjnu`1 p0)
at uzctz.qqdqx.nbfgy(denpl p0, denpl p1)
at uzctz.pnyow.flkmf(smlhw p0, smlhw p1)
at uzctz.pnyow.vurei(smlhw p0, smlhw p1)
at uzctz.pnyow.uzctz.jdrir`4.jhurj(Boolean p0)
at uzctz.pnyow.uzctz.jdrir`4.qpppp(pnyow p0)
at uzctz.radse.pfpaz(String p0)
at uzctz.mzltf.pfpaz(String p0)
at uzctz.mqxyu.pfpaz(String p0)
at uzctz.vlubb.mkpol(String p0)
at uzctz.wydud.neizt(dbozn p0, Int32 p1, jltdd p2)
at uzctz.wydud.ctbux(dbozn p0)
```

I do not have a class named `uzctz.xcdpf.uzctz.vafjj`. Does anyone know where this strange class name comes from?

Comment: Smells like *obfuscation*

Comment: ^^ And the reason, why it increases support effort.

Comment: what is your application kind/type here? are you doing anything unusual in the build?

Comment: Just a shot into the blue: If you are (obviously) not aware of using obfuscation and you happen to use Reflection, then obfuscation itself _can_ be the problem. That means you may need to take some extra steps or configs to make "it" work - whatever "it" is.